# Does Jetty server require EhCache core library as dependency?

Tags: java, jetty, ehcache

1. My Java application is using Jetty (v9.4) as server. I am wondering whether it requires `ehcache-core` as dependency for any reason such as Session management etc?
2. Would `ehcache-core` be required when the application is stateless?

Comment: If you use maven you can list all dependency with `mvn dependency:tree`

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse Jetty has no dependency on ehcache in any of it's components.

[Session Management in Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/session-management.html#jetty-sessions-architecture).

- Server has a `SessionIdManager`

  - Manages each `ServletContext` (eg: each deployed webapp)

    - A `SessionCache` per `ServletContext`

      - A `SessionDataStore` per `SessionCache`

There's no real options for `SessionIdManager` there's just one implementation.

For `SessionCache` you have the following implementations in Jetty.

- If unconfigured, you'll have a `DefaultSessionCache` (which itself cannot be configured)
- `session-cache-hash` - will use an in memory `HashMap` to track sessions.
- `session-cache-null` - will not cache `Session` at `ServletContext` level (this is sometimes a very useful configuration, just means you'll lean more on the `SessionDataStore`)

The `SessionCache` can be specifically configured at each `ServletContext`, but it can also be configured at the Server level via a `SessionCacheFactory` implementation that will be used when a new webapp is deployed.

For `SessionDataStore` you have several implementations available.

- Null - no storage of Sessions (you rely on Cache only)
- File - Session persistence to disk
- JDBC - Session persistence to a DataSource
- Cache - Session persistence to Memcache
- GCloud - Session persistence to Google Cloud Storage
- Mongo - Session persistence to Mongo DB
- Infinispan - Session persistence to Infinispan